# Scrollbars in datagrid control vb.net disappeared after Windows 10 Update KB5001337 KB5001406 - May 2021

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagrid, scrollbar, windows-update

Our desktop ERP built in VB.NET is suddenly not showing scrollbars in **DataGrid control** on Windows 10 after updates - **KB5001337, KB5001406 (May 2021)**

The space for the scrollbars appears but there are no up and down arrows visible!

Same application is showing the scrollbars in Datagrid control on Windows 7 PCs/ windows 10 without these updates.
We have multiple Datagrid controls throughout the application so need to find a fix asap

Windows.forms.Datagrid .NET Framework version 3 was used to build in VS 2010

Have already tried -

1. Settings -> Ease of Access-> Automatically hide scrollbars in Windows (turn off)
2. Tried running the ERP using Windows 7 compatibility mode

Comment: You forgot to mention the DataGrid of which GUI Platform. The .Net version in use is also missing.

Comment: @Jimi thanks , have added that information in original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uninstall KB5001337 and install KB5001566 this should resolve the issue.  Windows found the KB5001566 update automatically after I uninstalled the KB5001337 update.

Comment: Yes , this is what solved the issue for us on 90% systems

Comment: removing 337 did indeed fix the issue, but on next check updates it did not find 566 and instead installed 337

Answer (score 2):

Since our network administrator istn't capable of (de)-installing any updates in a short term view, we have found a workaround for this problem:

**You have to activate the XP-Styles in your Visual-Studio application settings** and the scrollbars are back!

A small disadvantage is that your application looks a little bit different, but the differnce is only small.

Comment: Will definitely try this out , thank you @Christoph!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I was too facing this issue. I have just uninstalled this update

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue with the KB5001337 on a windows 10 Version 1909. Updating to Windows 10 Version 20H2 resolved the issue here.